# Java задача Sum of even numbers

Tags: java

В задаче сказано реализуйте метод sum.

Правильная реализация должна получить массив значений int и вернуть сумму четных чисел.

Если  массив равен нулю или пуст, метод возвращает 0.
Метод sum не должен изменять массив.
Входной массив может содержать любое значение типа int от Integer.MIN_VALUE до
Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Мой код :

```
public static int sum(int[] array) {


int arr[] = new int[]{12, 34, 45, 21, 33, 4};

int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

sum += arr[i];

}

System.out.println( + sum);

return sum;

}

}
```

не понимаю как реализовать код хотя теорию читал с массивом беда помогите понять концепцию решения

Comment: Перенесите создание массива в main, а в sum передавайте его, и через return возвращайте оттуда результат.

Comment: а где в этом коде отбираются четные числа, если не секрет?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[]{1, 3, 2, 8, 15, 199};
        System.out.println(sum(array));
    }
    public static int sum(int[] array){
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
        {
            if(array[i] % 2 == 0)
                sum += array[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
}

Comment: Вопрос правьте, в комментариях нечитабельно

Comment: отлично, меняйте тип возвращаемого значения на лонг и добавляйте проверку массива на null и готово